# JFrog ConanCenter C++ Repository

Tags: c++, conan

I work in a software house and we use [conan](https://conan.io/) to install libraries (third parties and even the ones we developed inside the team) in our development machines.

As you may know the Bintray repository was shut down from last May. Now I wonder:

1. Do conan center offer some kind of long term support on the packages it hosts?
2. Do you distribute libraries from conan repository or do you upload libraries in your own private repository so that you are not affected by repository being shutting down?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Do conan center offer some kind of long term support on the packages it hosts?

Yes. Conan Center didn't change and won't, the official packages are still there.

However, official new packages must be added by [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/)

> Do you distribute libraries from conan repository or do you upload libraries in your own private repository so that you are not affected by repository being shutting down?

Conan Center Index uploads their packages (which contain built libraries) to an Artifactory instance. The same server provides those packages for all users.

In summary, nothing changed for package consumers. However, if you used to provide Conan packages through Bintray, now you should use [Artifactory Cloud](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/start-free/?isConan=true) (Free version), or even, you can install a local Artifactory instance (also free) and use it for distribution.

Please, read the official Blog post related to Bintray Sunset for more information:

https://blog.conan.io/2021/02/05/JFrog-announces-sunset-bintray.html

https://blog.conan.io/2021/03/31/Bintray-sunset-timeline.html

Comment: Yeah I know that conan center can still be used. My questions were: what if JFrog shuts down conan center? Are vcpkg repository safer from that point of view? Is it better to copy libraries in a private repository to avoid being involved by conan center being shutting down?

Comment: It won't happen! Bintray was closed, and wasn't not related to Conan only, because Bintray was generic proposed, which included other package formats too. The idea behind was to switching from Bintray to Artifactory, and that's it. No way for dropping Conan package support.

Comment: And in the worst case scenario, ConanCenter is also built from a unique Github repo containing all the recipes: the https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/ repo. So if the server itself went down, it is always possible to build the packages from source from the repo.